# Enlarging the datagrid cell on focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a 2-column 3-row WPF datagrid of (6) pictures inside a window that has fixed height and width. I want to make this happen: when the user clicks on a cell, the picture will be enlarged to either a popup-like window or to fill the entire grid; and when clicking on this single/focused picture, it will go back to its original position. (Note: I don't want to use pop-up window to do this.)